# Python Scraper File Naming

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a script based off LiteScraper from github, to scrape memes and gifs from http://ifunny.co

The script saves all images in folders with a timestamp, for example "ifunny-(timestamp)"

I am scraping from http://ifunny.co/feeds/shuffle, so I get a random page with 10 images each time.

The problem is, I need to modify the script so it saves all images in a given folder name.

I have tried to remove the code that adds the timestamp, but the problem is every time it gets up to 10 images and scrapes the next page, the 10 new images overwrite the older images.

The script seems to name the images like "1, 2, 3, 4" ect

Here is the code:

```
import os
import time
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

#todo: char support for Windows
#deal with triple backslash filter
#recursive parser option


class LiteScraper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.lastStartTag="No-Tag"
        self.lastAttributes=[]
        self.lastImgUrl=""
        self.Data=[]
        self.acceptedTags=["div","p","h","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","ul","li","a","img"]
        self.counter=0
        self.url=""


        self.SAVE_DIR="" #/Users/stjepanbrkic/Desktop/temp
        self.Headers=["User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"]

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        #print("Encountered a START tag:",tag)
        self.lastStartTag=tag
        self.lastAttributes=attrs #unnecesarry, might come in hany

        if self.lastStartTag=="img":
            attrs=self.lastAttributes

            for attribute in attrs:
                if attribute[0]=="src":
                    self.lastImgUrl=attribute[1]
                    print(attribute[1])

                    #Allow GIF from iFunny to download
                    for attribute in attrs:
                        if attribute[0]=="data-gif":
                            self.lastImgUrl=attribute[1]
                            print(attribute[1])
                            #End Gif Code

            self.handle_picture(self.lastImgUrl)

    def handle_endtag(self,tag):
        #print("Encountered a END tag:",tag)
        pass

    def handle_data(self,data):
        data=data.replace("\n"," ")
        data=data.replace("\t"," ")
        data=data.replace("\r"," ")
        if self.lastStartTag in self.acceptedTags:
            if not data.isspace():
                print("Encountered some data:",data)
                self.Data.append(data)

        else:
            print("Encountered filtered data.") #Debug

    def handle_picture(self,url):
        print("Bumped into a picture. Downloading it now.")
        self.counter+=1
        if url[:2]=="//":
            url="http:"+url

        extension=url.split(".")
        extension="."+extension[-1]

        try:
            req=urllib.request.Request(url)
            req.add_header(self.Headers[0],self.Headers[1])
            response=urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10)
            picdata=response.read()
            file=open(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics/"+str(self.counter)+extension,"wb")
            file.write(picdata)
            file.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Something went wrong, sorry.")


    def start(self,url):
        self.url=url
        self.checkSaveDir()

        try: #wrapped in exception - if there is a problem with url/server
            req=urllib.request.Request(url)
            req.add_header(self.Headers[0],self.Headers[1])
            response=urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10)
            siteData=response.read().decode("utf-8")
            self.feed(siteData)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        self.__init__()  #resets the parser/scraper for serial parsing/scraping
        print("Done!")

    def checkSaveDir(self):
        #----windows support
        if os.name=="nt":
            container="\ "
            path=os.path.normpath(__file__)
            path=path.split(container[0])
            path=container[0].join(path[:len(path)-1])
            path=path.split(container[0])
            path="/".join(path)
        #no more windows support! :P
        #for some reason, os.normpath returns path with backslashes
        #on windows, so they had to be supstituted with fowardslashes.

        else:
            path=os.path.normpath(__file__)
            path=path.split("/")
            path="/".join(path[:len(path)-1])

        foldername=self.url[7:]
        foldername=foldername.split("/")[0]

        extension=time.strftime("iFunny")+"-"+time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "-" + time.strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss")

        self.SAVE_DIR=path+"/"+foldername+"-"+extension


        if not os.path.exists(self.SAVE_DIR):
            os.makedirs(self.SAVE_DIR)

        if not os.path.exists(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics"):
            os.makedirs(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics")

        print(self.SAVE_DIR)
```

and this is what I am running to use the script:

pastebin dot com/PNwJ9wEJ

Sorry for the pastebin, it wont let me post my code...

I am very new to python so I am not sure how to fix this. Is it possible to make it so it does this?

Page 1 image names: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
Page 2 image names: (11, 12, 13....)

Answer (score 0):

Every time your parser is instantiated (so for every new page), the `counter` is set to zero. That's why the images keep getting overwritten.

One alternative would be to determine what filenames are already used.

```
i = 0
while os.path.isfile('your_filename_logic_'+str(i)):
    i += 1
# Now i is the first number which hasn't been used.
```

But if you get to thousands of images, this might not be as fast as you'd want.

You could store the counter in a file after the `LiteScraper` finishes, and read it back when the next one starts up.

```
def startMyNewCounter(self):
    if os.path.isfile('your_filename_logic_' + 'count'):
        with open('your_filename_logic_'+'count', 'r') as f:
            self.counter = int(next(f))
    else:
        self.counter = 0

def saveMyCounter(self):
    with open('your_filename_logic_'+'count', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(self.counter) + '\n')
```

Or the simplest answer: if you don't care about your images after the program closes, you could make the counter a global variable rather than a member of your `LiteScraper`. So every new `LiteScraper` picks up where the last one left off.